# Sharing pears and bananas

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> Per has $3$ bananas and $5$ pears. Olav asks if he could have some fruit
>   and Per agrees. What is the probability that he receives half ($1/2$) a
>   pear and three quarters ($3/4$) of a banana?

This was taken from a recent exam in Norway. Is there a way to solve it without knowing how many pieces the fruit is divided into? What about the continuous case?

Comment: Does Per realize a random variable $X \sim U[0,1]$ to decide how much fruit to give to Olav?

Comment: At the very least, the scheme of how to cut up the fruits is missing, and the probability distribution of how they will share is missing. Without these two, I don't think you can solve this.

Comment: Seems like just a random chunk is removed from both fruits is a logical assumption. Eg interpret the 5 pears as one big pear.

Comment: almost surely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume the pears are cut into halves and the bananas into quarters and read "1/2" as "at least 1/2" and "3/4" as "at least 3/4" and that the divisions are uniform and independent, the probability would be 
$$
\frac{9}{10} \times \frac{9}{12} = \frac{27}{40} = 0.675 .
$$